# Error: message[From HTTPUtil::getHttpRequest():Bytes to read is less then ZERO?

Tags: c#

This code sends a  request to a server. I am opening a socket using  a endpoint.  I have trouble with POST content length. I am not using HttpWebRequst but a socket (from our client platform), which connects to their server platform.  This is to send one long string request.

```
Header = POST /OKMMIS  HTTP/5.1 
Request = header + content
Content-length = content.length
Content = @"ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*500000355      *ZZ*734476619      *130711*1023*^*00501*790719345*0*T*:~GS*HS*500000355*734476619*20130711*1023*273450*X*005010X279A1~ST*270*0001*005010X279A1~BHT*0022*13*635091349826842989*20130711*1023~HL*1**20*1~NM1*PR*2*Oklahoma Medicaid*****PI*734476619~HL*2*1*21*1~NM1*1P*2*Hillcrest Medical Center*****XX*1629057229~HL*3*2*22*0~TRN*1*20130711102317CDN266905*9CARDONHCN~NM1*IL*1*MESSNDREW*MARQUIS****MI*B10083667~REF*SY*323006707~DMG*D8*20100108*M~DTP*291*D8*20130512~EQ*30~SE*14*0001~GE*1*273450~IEA*1*790719345~";
```

The call `m_socClient.Send(requestBytes)` sends this message.

Their receiving sever logs gives this error:

> message[From HTTPUtil::getHttpRequest():Bytes to read is less then ZERO ???, req->headerLengh is 49, req->contentLength is 486 and we have already read 537 bytes

Header length = 51. Content length= 486. But the server reads 539 bytes? I am getting a HTTP 400 Bad Request. This is the Response from Server

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length: 539

POST /OKMMISPOS  HTTP/5.1 
Content-Length: 486


ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*500000355      *ZZ*734476619      *130718*1129*^*00501*936078483*0*T*:~GS*HS*500000355*734476619*20130718*1129*326565*X*005010X279A1~ST*270*0001*005010X279A1~BHT*0022*13*635097437938418629*20130718*1129~HL*1**20*1~NM1*PR*2*Oklahoma Medicaid*****PI*734476619~HL*2*1*21*1~NM1*1P*2*Hillcrest Medical Center*****XX*1629057229~HL*3*2*22*0~NM1*IL*1*MARQUIS*****MI*B17993667~DMG*D8*20101208*M~DTP*291*D8*20130512~EQ*30~SE*12*0001~GE*1*326565~IEA*1*936078483~
```

Where do I even start?

```
//// create a new client socket ...
string szIPSelected = "127.0.0.1";
int szPort = 50050;
m_socClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
System.Net.IPAddress remoteIPAddress = System.Net.IPAddress.Parse(szIPSelected);
System.Net.IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new System.Net.IPEndPoint(remoteIPAddress, szPort);

m_socClient.Connect(remoteEndPoint);

if (m_socClient.Connected)
{
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connected to " + szIPSelected + ":" + szPort;
    statusStrip1.Refresh();

    string resource = "/OKMMISPOS";
    var header = String.Format("POST {0}  HTTP/5.1 " + Environment.NewLine, resource);
    String body = @"ISA*00*          *00*          *ZZ*500000355      *ZZ*734476619      *130711*1023*^*00501*790719345*0*T*:~GS*HS*500000355*734476619*20130711*1023*273450*X*005010X279A1~ST*270*0001*005010X279A1~BHT*0022*13*635091349826842989*20130711*1023~HL*1**20*1~NM1*PR*2*Oklahoma Medicaid*****PI*734476619~HL*2*1*21*1~NM1*1P*2*Hillcrest Medical Center*****XX*1629057229~HL*3*2*22*0~TRN*1*20130711102317CDN266905*9CARDONHCN~NM1*IL*1*MESSNDREW*MARQUIS****MI*B10083667~REF*SY*323006707~DMG*D8*20100108*M~DTP*291*D8*20130512~EQ*30~SE*14*0001~GE*1*273450~IEA*1*790719345~";
    byte[] bodyBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(body);
    header += "Content-Length: " + (bodyBytes.Length) + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
    string request = String.Concat(header, body);
    textBox3.Text = request;
    textBox3.Refresh();
    byte[] requestBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(request);
    m_socClient.Send(requestBytes);
    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Sending  Request to  " + szIPSelected + ":" + szPort;
    statusStrip1.Refresh();
}

Thread.Sleep(3000);

byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int bytesRec = m_socClient.Receive(bytes);

txtResponse271.Text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);

m_socClient.Disconnect(true);
m_socClient.Close();
```

Comment: _"Where I even start?"_ - by properly explaining what you are trying to do, what the code does and what you tried to understand this error.

Comment: @CodeCaster: Ok done.. Please suggest.

Comment: It's their server, ask them why their code shows that error. Why don't you use an http client from the .NET framework? Your request sends `HTTP/5.1` and you're missing the `host` header if you're trying to construct a valid HTTP/1.1 request, which their server might be complaining about. Also instead of `Thread.Sleep()` really just keep calling `socket.receive()` until it returns a value indicating the end of the transmission (for example `0`).

Comment: I am not missing the host header. They don't need one.This is a tunnel. Only can send a receive using one port. And my socket uses that IP and port as endpoint. My client code is where the problem is.

Comment: Then you've still got some explanation to do. :-) What kind of server _are_ you connecting to? Is it not a HTTP/1.1 server? Then we can't possibly know what message format they expect and why their server throws the error you show. Did they explicitly tell you not to send a host header? Don't they have sample code? What do you mean by "having trouble with content length"? Can you see using for example [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/) what exactly you send? Why do you append three newlines? Are you sure `Environment.NewLine` contains `"\r\n"`?

Comment: :) Ok my client is not techy. He tells me to use HTTP 5.1 in the Post. But when I see the server response, it returns a HTTP 1.1. So I am beginning to think it is HTTP 1.1. Can we try for both cases